# Получить все индексы пустых строк в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Есть текст:

---

Put you on the rocks too, baby (Yeah)
Bring you to the block too, baby (Yeah)
What you want? 'Cause I want you, yeah (Oow)
Ah, ah, ah, ah, ah, ah, ah, in love with you (Yeah, baby, ooh)
Drop, drop, drop, drop, drop, drop, drop, yeah (Yeah, baby)

You know my buddies saying
Leck, leck, leck, leck, leck, leck, leck
You know my girlies saying
Leck, leck, leck, leck, leck, leck, leck
Ah, and everybody saying

---

Полностью весь текст:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить все индексы ( если они есть ) пустых строк в тексте? Может быть возможно узнать индексы всех невидимых "/n/n" в тексте ?

Comment: В тексте  только одна пустая строка может быть?

Comment: Больше, но не более 15

Comment: Могут ли быть пустые строки в начали или в конце текста?

Comment: Нет, таких строк нет

Comment: а строка совсем пустая ? даже \n нет ?

Comment: Когда написал код для проверки с которым произошла ошибка, увидел в тексте все /n, но если просто вывести текст, то вы увидете то, что выше, я пытался найти в тексте /n но безуспешно

Answer (score 2):

```py
text = """An example using weather data provided by the API at OpenWeatherMap
Introduction

Want to know how to use PostgreSQL' s great functionality to work with JSON objects?

Novelties

Here is a concise list of the most important new features:

    new datatype: json
    new operators: ->, ->>, #> and #>>
    new functions: json_array_length, json_extract_path, json_array_elements and many more

The full list of JSON specific functions can be found at:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html.
General Usage of the Operators

Let’s get a quick overview concerning the main usage and differences among the three operators.

The operators -> and ->> are easy to use and allow you to point to a specific child element."""

print([a for a, b in enumerate(text.split('\n')) if not b])
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 14, 17, 19]
```

Для файла это будет выглядеть так

```py
file = open('example.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
print([a for a, b in enumerate(file.readlines()) if b == '\n'])
file.close()
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 14, 17, 19]
```

Comment: Это не совсем то, что я хотел, если попытаться добавить через цикл, перед этими номерами что-то получится чушь

Comment: В первой строке 80 символов, 81 это пустая строка - это то, что мне нужно

Comment: @MaximChyorny значит Вы не совсем корретно сформулировали задачу. То, о чем Вы сейчас говорите, называется конец строки или символ новой строки там еще можно повспоминать, но никак не "пустая строка". У символа "новой строки" в строке индекс (если мы говорим об индексах, а не о порядковом номере и если этот символ в строке присутствует) всегда равен `-1` а его положительный индекс  всегда будет `len(line) - 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
s = '''Know you see that they been tryna be me lately I'm a heavy hitter like Gervonta Davis That shit ain't gon' save 'em, leave 'em on the pavement All I know is get this motherfuckin' paper

[Chorus: Lil Baby] Thou shall not try one of us, if they do, I'ma bust Please don't reach for no chain Not 'bout the set, but it's more 'bout respect If they get me upset, they gon' die, that's on gang

Know you see that they been tryna be me lately I'm a heavy hitter like Gervonta Davis That shit ain't gon' save 'em, leave 'em on the pavement All I know is get this motherfuckin' paper




[Chorus: Lil Baby] Thou shall not try one of us, if they do, I'ma bust Please don't reach for no chain Not 'bout the set, but it's more 'bout respect If they get me upset, they gon' die, that's on gang'''
 
 
 
def findall(sub, string):
    index = -1
    try:
        while True:
            index = string.index(sub, index + 1)
            yield index
    except ValueError:
        pass
 
for i in findall('\n\n', s):
    print(i)
```

На основе [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3874760/7485582) [@intuited](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192812/intuited)

https://ideone.com/A0BxO5

Ещё можно так:

```
import re
res = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r'(?=(\n\n))', s)]
```

На основе [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664889/7485582) [@moinudin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89806/moinudin)

Comment: Вставил код, ничего не изменив с переменной s, запустил - не работает.

Comment: Что не работает? Я же ссылку даже на онлайн интерпретатор оставил.

Comment: Зашёл в интерпретатор, там работает, у меня нет. Версия python 3.9.5

Comment: Вы можете чётко ответить, что именно не работает?

Comment: Я не знаю, честно. Я просто вставляю ваши отправленные коды, у меня в терминале запускается код и спустя секунду завершается, я не очень хорош в программировании, написал в конце print(res) - там пустой список

Comment: Куда вы вставляете код? Тот код, который в ответе, работает. Вторая версия ничего не выводит на экран, нужно добавить для этого печать. Добавьте в вопрос информацию о том, что вы делаете. Можно скриншот.

Comment: https://ibb.co/j8JMSnm также https://ibb.co/jMRy0gw

Comment: Я понял, в чём проблема. Пустые строки в ответе на самом деле содержат пробелы. Так скопировалось. Сейчас поправлю.